# How do I get my usb devices working in Windows 7 on Asus H110M-K D3

Tags: windows-7, usb-3

I installed Windows 7 from an image using Clonezilla.

I added drivers, including Intel USB3 Windows 7 driver downloaded from the support page for this motherboard, by copying the files to the C drive from a Linux Mint liveusb (Clonezilla does not include write support when mounting NTFS partitions). I then went to the device manager to install drivers.

Installation went fine and I have now a device named Intel USB 3.0 Extensible Host Controller.

However, when I connect any USB mouse or other usb device, Windows does not find them. It does not even give them any electricity. This, while those same devices work fine before getting into Windows. All four mice I tried work in the UEFI, and both the usb flash disks could be used with this computer to boot into other OSes.

How can I get them to work?

There are two USB related settings in the UEFI, and I have tried all four combinations to no avail.

Comment: While in windows install the usb 3 drivers using the Intel installer.

Comment: That's what I did, and now I have the controller, but it still does not work, the devices don't even get electricity.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it. It turned out that since I ran the AsusSetup.exe file instead of the setup.exe file, only the xHCI controller was installed.

I'd seen only one usb device in the device manager and was surprised about it, and tried to add a generic USB root hub, but only now when I looked at what is included in the driver on the Intel website did I see that I really have to have the root hub from the driver installation.

Rerunning the install, but now from the other file fixed the issue.